# How to count frequency of values across the entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

hello I have the following dataset:
[image]
I want to count the frequency of each value occuring across the entire dataset. I am aware of the value_count() which is works only on columns but not for the entire dataset.
I used the following code:

```
df.value_counts()
```

But it results in an error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'
```

Please could you help me count the frequency of values across the whole dataset?

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.** Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) function to stack all values in one column, and then use `value_counts`:

```
df.stack().value_counts()
```

Comment: nice one, I'dd add in `pd.melt(df)['value'].value_counts()` as well

Comment: could you tell me what is the difference between melt and stack?

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJsiiPK5sxs) video explains it pretty well @tulock